# Color interpolation in Fragment Shader GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, gpu

I need to map a scalar value to color that ranges 0 to 1. It will go from GREEN to RED (from 0 to 1) Linear Interpolation using the texture co-ordinates (also ranges from 0 to 1)

I'm new to OpenGL and GLSL, so far I have figured out that I need to write color value in

```
gl_FragColor
```

which is a vector of dimension 4. I'm not sure how I can calculate the R, G and B channels for gl_FragColor just by one scalar value that ranges for 0 to 1.0 (It will from GREEN to RED and at 0.5 it will be WHITE)

Comment: Are you using a 1D texture, or taking a scalar from >= 2D UVs?

Comment: Each pixel in 2D texture gives value from 0 to 1

Comment: Okay. The coordinates are irrelevant to the question then.

Comment: Im getting scalar value from 2D texture pixel

Comment: That really makes no sense, unfortunately. You claim to have a single texture coordinate from 0 to 1 (so far that makes sense), but then you mention a 2D texture... you need two coordinates to lookup a value from a 2D texture unless you assume the other one is constant *(in which case a 1D texture would make more sense)*.

Comment: I have a 2D texture (and I definitely need 2 co-ordinates to look it up), the scalar value that I get after using the both co-ordinates ranges from 0 to 1). I am using that scalar value to interpolate between colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#version 120

...

float remap( float minval, float maxval, float curval )
{
    return ( curval - minval ) / ( maxval - minval );
} 

...

const vec4 GREEN = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
const vec4 WHITE = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
const vec4 RED   = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

float u = <whatever, grabbed from a uniform?>;
u = clamp( u, 0.0, 1.0 );
if( u < 0.5 )
    gl_FragColor = mix( GREEN, WHITE, remap( 0.0, 0.5, u ) );
else
    gl_FragColor = mix( WHITE, RED, remap( 0.5, 1.0, u ) );
```

Or you could sample a 3-pixel 1D texture.

Comment: Never ever branch in the fs is not absolutely avoidable. Even on the most modern hardware fragments are evaluated in blocks of 4 and all branches that or taken in any of them forces the gpu to evaluate them for every fragment regardless of wether needed or not. Furthermore it's all about coherence. Fragments close to another should be as "coherent" (take the same branches) as possible as that may result in only the necessary branches to be run.

Comment: To solve the problem of avoiding branches one should always use functions like `mix`, `step`, `smoothstep`, etc as they are faster even if the branching is as coherent as possible. Of course there are corner cases where that is not true, but generally that advice is worth its weight in gold.

Answer (score 3):

If your value in the range 0 to 1 is named `val`:

```
if (val < 0.5)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(2.0 * val, 1.0, 2.0 * val, 1.0);
}
else
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 2.0 * (1.0 - val), 2.0 * (1.0 - val), 1.0);
}
```

Or if you want to avoid branch statements:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(min(2.0 * val, 1.0),
                    min(2.0 * (1.0 - val), 1.0), 
                    2.0 * min(val, 1.0 - val),
                    1.0);
```

Not sure if this would actually be faster. As pointed out by @Jessy, this can be simplified if the color buffer has a normalized format, because the output colors are automatically clamped to a [0, 1] range in that case, making a couple of the `min` calls unnecessary:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(2.0 * val,
                    2.0 * (1.0 - val), 
                    2.0 * min(val, 1.0 - val),
                    1.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about manual clamping, because gl_FragColor is clamped between 0-1.

```
float red = 2. * texel;
float green = 2. - red;
gl_FragColor = vec4(red, green, min(red, green), 1.);
```

Comment: True, at least as long as the color buffer has a normalized format, it could be simplified. I hadn't thought of that.